# Attempt to do recursion in Apex

Tags: apex, community, recursion

This simple method I wrote is an attempt to mimic the equivalent iterative method (I'm just curious about recursion in Apex). It must return the element of a list of custom objects that have the older Createddate.

I printed head and current list value for each recursion layer and the result is correct, but returning to the caller I had a "List out of bounds" error. Since base cases are covered, which further step do I need to do to avoid this error?

Let the size of COset = n, the index in which I got the error is always n-1.

```
public static customer_Obj__c solveQueueRic(List<customer_Obj__c> COset,Integer index,customer_Obj__c head){
        customer_Obj__c lg = COset[index];
        if(index == 0){
            head = lg;
            return solveQueueRic(COset,index+1,head);
        }
        if(index < COset.size()){
            if(lg.Createddate < COset[index].Createddate){
                head = lg;
            }
            return solveQueueRic(COset,index+1,head);
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do this directly with soql query or a for-loop?? p.s: i can't yet write a comment.

Comment: Because the list size counts a lot of records I use a method to filter them and then put each category in a list. Then for each list I call this method to have, for each category, the value I want. Your solution tryes to ignore recursion also, since the loop itself is a iterative paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because of this below line

```
customer_Obj__c lg = COset[index];
```

Lets say, size of `COset` is 4 i.e. you can go upto `index` 3, so when your code goes into recursion and when `index` reaches 4, it is bound to give you `List index out of bound` exception as there won't be any element at `index` 4 as `size` of your list is 4.

You can instead, move that above line inside your condition something like below

```
public static customer_Obj__c solveQueueRic(List<customer_Obj__c> COset,Integer index,customer_Obj__c head){
    customer_Obj__c lg;
    if(index == 0){
        lg = COset[index];
        head = lg;
        return solveQueueRic(COset,index+1,head);
    }
    if(index < COset.size()){
        lg = COset[index];
        if(lg.Createddate < COset[index].Createddate){
            head = lg;
        }
        return solveQueueRic(COset,index+1,head);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Damn, embarrassing moment here. Thank you Vijay!